# How to pass converted value of field for a specific validator in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, validation

Suppose I have a field for IP address. It has 2 validators
- Ip
- Db_NoRecordsExists

```
$ip = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('ip');
$ip->setLabel('IP')
   ->setRequired(true)
   ->addValidator('Ip')
   ->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', false, array('table' => 'blacklist_ips', 'field' => 'ip'));
```

In DB ip stored as integer, so I have a problem with validation on unique, using Db_NoRecordsExists.

Is it possible to pass ip as converted to integer, but only for one of validator (because in case of converting field value before validate, Ip validator will gives error), something like this (added new parameter "value"):

```
$ip->setLabel('IP')
   ->setRequired(true)
   ->addValidator('Ip')
   ->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', false, array('table' => 'blacklist_ips', 'field' => 'ip', 'value' => Custom_Convert_Ip::ip2long([value_of_ip])));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to write your own validator `Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists`. For example:

```
class My_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists extends Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists {
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        return parent::isValid(new Zend_Db_Expr("INET_ATON('$value')"));
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it I think it should do the trick.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I made something like this (created own validator which converts ip to int before validation) and it works OK, but I really curious if exists a universal way to do that, so no need to create validator for each of new data converting.

Comment: @Vovkin. I don't think that there exist any universal way of doing it. For validating against db you have only RecordExists and NoRecordExists validators. They don't have any method for modifying or transforming value of the $value.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, but I'm talking not only about concrete validation against db, but about possibility of modifying value before sending it to validator at all. As for me it's a logically to have such a possibility for Zend_Validate, but I can't find nothing.

Comment: @Vovkin. Probably this will not apply to this situation, but normally you can add filters to your form elements. Validation is performed on the filtered values.